# Two CNOT gates on two Two qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

[image]

Suppose we have two qubits in the state  $(a|0⟩+b|1⟩)|0⟩ $, to which we apply the following circuit.
Specify the state of each qubit after we applied the circuit to the state  (a|0⟩+b|1⟩)|0⟩ . Let the first qubit be in the resulting state  α|0⟩+β|1⟩ , and the second in  γ|0⟩+δ|1⟩ . Specify the resulting amplitudes  α,β,γ,δ  in terms of the initial amplitudes  a,b .
I have tried my best to do question 10, the resultant state I got is a|00>+b|01> which I don't understand how can be represented as tensor product of two states as for it to be b=0 which is a contradiction, maybe I am doing the CNOT operation wrong. In any case please help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initial state:  (a|0⟩+b|1⟩)|0⟩=a|00⟩+b|10⟩
After the first CNOT:  a|00⟩+b|11⟩
After the second CNOT:  a|00⟩+b|01⟩=|0⟩(a|0⟩+b|1⟩)
So α,β,γ,δ are 1, 0, a and b respectively.

Answer (score 0):

### METHOD $1$

\begin{align*}
(a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>)\left|0\right>&=a\left|00\right>+b\left|10\right>\\
&\stackrel{CNOT}{\longrightarrow}a\left|00\right>+b\left|11\right>\\&\stackrel{CNOT}{\longrightarrow}a\left|00\right>+b\left|01\right>=\left|0\right>(a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>)&(\text{Swap!})\\
&=(\alpha\left|0\right>+\beta\left|1\right>)(\gamma\left|0\right>+\delta\left|1\right>)\\
&\Rightarrow \alpha=1,\beta=0,\gamma=a,\delta=1
\end{align*}
by mere observation.

---

### METHOD $2$

*Assuming* that it can be broken into two pure states or that the result is not entangled, we can write
\begin{align*}
a\left|00\right>+b\left|01\right>&=\alpha\gamma\left|00\right>+\alpha\delta\left|01\right>+\beta\gamma\left|10\right>+\beta\delta\left|11\right>
\end{align*}

Comparing gives
\begin{align*}
\alpha\gamma&=a\tag{1}\\
\alpha\delta&=b\tag{2}\\
\beta\gamma&=0\tag{3}\\
\beta\delta&=0\tag{4}\\
(1)-(2)\Rightarrow\alpha(\gamma-\delta)&=a-b\\
(3)-(4)\Rightarrow\beta(\gamma-\delta)&=0\Rightarrow \beta=0&(\because \gamma\neq\delta\text{ from equation }(5))\\
\Rightarrow \alpha=1,\gamma=a,\delta&=b&(\because \gamma^2+\delta^2=1,a^2+b^2=1)
\end{align*}

---

Method $1$ can go for uncomplicated factorization whereas Method $2$ should be incorporated for complicated factorization, and proving entangled states by the contradiction of the assumption.

Comment: the first step is wrong as state is (a|0⟩+b|1⟩)|0> so it would be a|00>+b|10>

Comment: @Heriotic Thanks! I edited it. I don't know how I read that $(a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>)(a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>)$ instead of $(a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>)\left|0\right>$. Perhaps, you didn't enter it in mathjax earlier or I blacked out.